# Is there a way to convert TSUNG scripts into jMeter scripts?

Tags: jmeter, tsung

I've inherited a collection of TSUNG Performance Test scripts. There was no handover and there is no knowledge within the company about TSUNG. The technical challenge to learn TSUNG in a short timeframe is quite big.

I was wondering if there is a tool or a way to convert TSUNG scripts into jMeter scripts?

I've googled it already, but I couldn't find anything.

Regards
Urs

I've searched the web and I'm hoping to find a way to convert those scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any existing "converter", if Tsung test is using [HTTP Protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) you can consider [running your Tsung scripts using JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) as a [proxy](https://github.com/processone/tsung/issues/120), this way JMeter will intercept the requests and generate relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers and [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager).

You will need to implement [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) yourself which might comparable to learning Tsung if your script is big enough (or alternatively consider automated correlation solutions like BlazeMeter Proxy Recorder)